# If $R$ is a ring and $M$ be any maximal ideal with $a\notin M$, then there exists $q\in M$ and $s\in R$ such that forall $r\in R$ $r=sar+qr$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

If $R$ is a ring and $M$ be any maximal ideal with $a\notin M$, then there exists $q\in M$ and $s\in R$ such that forall $r\in R$ we have $r=sar+qr$. Also show that this is true only when $M$ is maximal ideal. I am assuming $R$ is commutative and $1\in R$. Please help me. I am unable to proceed.

Comment: *Hint:* Show that the ideal $(a) + M$ is the whole ring (use $a \notin M$). Then $1=sa+q$, for some $s\in R$ and $q\in M$.

Comment: Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x], P=(x).$ Then $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$, but *not* maximal ideal. Now $1-x \notin P$, but every element $r \in R$ can be written as $r=r(1-x) +rx$. This gives a counter example of you second claim: "it is true only when $M$ is a maximal ideal". I guess you want to say "this need not be true if $M$ is not a maximal ideal".

Comment: Please search for your question before posting, thanks. I know it isn't always possible to find duplicates, but it's good advice anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $b\notin M\implies M\subsetneqq \langle b\rangle+M. $ As $\langle b \rangle+M$ is an ideal of $R$ and $M\subsetneqq \langle b\rangle +M\subseteq R  $. Since $M$ is maximal, $\langle b\rangle +M=R$. Since $1\in R\implies \exists\ s\in    R$ and $q\in M$ such that $$ 1=bs+q\implies a=sba+qa $$